# How do I loop different sections inside a contentful landing page with php

Tags: php, contentful, contentful-api

Using the php SDK, I would like to get all the content for a landing page, this will include sections with different content types / components with different fields per entry.

eg.

Section 1 - hero

Section 2 - article

Section 3 - image

**Q. How do I loop through and get the linked section content.**

> If an entry contains a link to an asset or another
> entry, the SDK will automatically load it.

I am struggling to understand the [documentation](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/php/tutorials/getting-started-with-contentful-and-php/). How exactly do I break into these values?

```
<?php
$query = new \Contentful\Delivery\Query();
$query->setContentType('page_landing')
->where("fields.urlHandle[match]", $slug);

$products = $client->getEntries($query);

foreach ($products as $product) {

echo $product['name'];

// Example of what I am trying to achieve
    if($product['sections']['id']=='hero'){
      $title= $product['sections']['hero']['title'];
    } 
    if($product['sections']['id']=='article'){
      $text = $product['sections']['article']['text'];
    } 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would love to know if there is a better way, the documentation does not have many examples. Below is where I ended up but feel there must be a simpler way.

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'vendor/credentials.php';

// if we need to use rich text 
$renderer = new \Contentful\RichText\Renderer();

// Get the section entry id's
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $dataJson     = json_encode($product);
    $revertJson[] = json_decode($dataJson, true);
    foreach ($revertJson as $Json) {
        foreach ($Json['fields']['sections'] as $entries) {
            $entryID[] = $entries['sys']['id'];
        }
    }
}

// Loop out the sections
foreach ($entryID as $entry) {
    // Get individual linked entries
    $entry = $client->getEntry($entry);
    $type  = $entry->getSystemProperties()->getcontentType();
    $json  = json_encode($type);
    $comp  = json_decode($json, true);
    if ($comp['sys']['id'] == 'Hero') {
        // field
        echo $entry['urlHandle'];
        // rich text
        echo $renderer->render($entry['text']);
        // asset
        $asset = $client->getAsset($entry['imageId']);
        echo $asset->getFile()->getUrl();
    } elseif ($comp['sys']['id'] == 'Landmark') {
        echo $entry['title'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Any updates on this?  I'm running into the same issue.